# Async Socket.BeginReceive internal call mystery

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I have a receive callback from an async client method that is supposed to call `socket.BeginReceive` internally to check if data is done being sent. The code is as follows:

```
    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, 
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                File.AppendAllText(DataDisplay.Properties.Settings.Default.rawDataLog, response + "\r\n");
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```

The problem with this is that when the code reaches the `client.BeginReceive` call, nothing happens. I know that sounds vague, so let me try to explain. I have set breakpoints throughout the code to see where it could possibly be going, and I can't figure it out. I have tried the `else` case, the beginning of the `ReceiveCallback`, where the `receivedone.Set()` returns to in the main code, the `catch` statement, etc. to no avail.

The part that is most confusing is that when I run it with a test server I wrote, it works as I would expect. This code is essentially from the MSDN example on async sockets, in case it looks familiar. Only when I try it with the third party device, I get stymied.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that while you are debugging, nothing is actually being received so its essentially permanently waiting on the receive thread?  Note that `BeginReceive` will use a `ThreadPool` thread, and will callback to the method you post.  If its not calling back, then my first impression is that its not received anything.

Comment: When I probe the StateObject, it has received a string of data and has stored it, and the code does get to the point where it attempts to call client.BeginReceive again. Shouldn't at least re-enter the ReceiveCallback, even if there is nothing else left, or am I confused?

Comment: If there isn't a timeout specified, it will wait - not sure about the underlying implementation.

Comment: I'd advise reviewing the documentation about how to use the method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxkwh6zw.aspx

Comment: The callback in this instance is only used when the method is ready to finish - this will usually be the cause in all async patterns, as the purpose of the callback is to stop you needing to wait on the finish or poll - you can be notified.  In your example, its not finishing because its waiting for a buffers read (or the read to complete, not sure how its implemented).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I think this puts me on track. This all gets quite confusing sometimes. Thank you very much for your help.